# Getting Console errors in angular application

Tags: angular12

Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ambient-light-sensor'.
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'battery'.
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'document-domain'.
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'navigation-override'.
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'speaker'.
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/atoms.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/polyfills.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/escape.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/playback.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/assets/record.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMNodeInserted' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated () and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMNodeInserted' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated () and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMNodeInserted' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated () and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMNodeInserted' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated () and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMNodeInserted' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated () and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMNodeInserted' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated () and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.
[Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMNodeInserted' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated () and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.